# Using @link with aliases in kDoc

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kdoc

In Java documentation I can do the following:

```
/**
*  {@link FancyComp mFancy} is a variable that you need
*/
```

How do I do this in Kotlin doc for the same result of course?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@link` doesn't exist in kDoc but can easily be replaced by [Inline Markup](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#inline-markup).

from KotlinDoc [Linking to Elements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html#linking-to-elements)

> **Inline Markup**
>
> For inline markup, KDoc uses the regular [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) syntax, extended to
>   support a shorthand syntax for linking to other elements in the code.
>
> **Linking to Elements**
>
> To link to another element (class, method, property or parameter),
>   simply put its name in square brackets:
>
> Use the method `[foo]` for this purpose.
>
> If you want to specify a custom
>   label for the link, use the Markdown reference-style syntax:
>
> Use `[this method][foo]` for this purpose. You can also use qualified
>   names in the links. Note that, unlike JavaDoc, qualified names always
>   use the dot character to separate the components, even before a method
>   name:
>
> Use `[kotlin.reflect.KClass.properties]` to enumerate the properties of
>   the class. Names in links are resolved using the same rules as if the
>   name was used inside the element being documented. In particular, this
>   means that if you have imported a name into the current file, you
>   don't need to fully qualify it when you use it in a KDoc comment.
>
> Note that KDoc does not have any syntax for resolving overloaded
>   members in links. Since the Kotlin documentation generation tool puts
>   the documentation for all overloads of a function on the same page,
>   identifying a specific overloaded function is not required for the
>   link to work.